# Strange behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 elements - "span" (named "divLikedX") and "a" (named "aLikeX"). I have the following javascript (occurs clicking by "a"):

```
    function CommentLike(CommentID, aLink) {
        if (CommentID != null && CommentID > 0)
            $.post("/Home/LikeComment", { CommentID: CommentID },
            function () {
                //alert($("#divLiked" + CommentID).is(':visible'));
                /*alert($(aLink).text());*/if ($("#divLiked" + CommentID).is(':hidden')) {
                    $("#divLiked" + CommentID).show();
                    $("#aLike" + CommentID).text('Unlike');
                } else {
                    $("#divLiked" + CommentID).hide();
                    $("#aLike" + CommentID).text('Like');
                }
            });
        };
```

If I remove `$("#aLike" + CommentID).text('Unlike');` and `$("#aLike" + CommentID).text('Like');` strings I get the correct behavior. But with these strings it works correctly only first 2 clicks, after it `alert($("#divLiked" + CommentID).is(':visible')) == "true"` always. Why?

Comment: tip: the second line can be replaced by `if (CommentID)`

Comment: My only suggestion is to "inspect element" with FF or chrome at the start and after each click to see what attributes the div gets.

Comment: Is either of these elements the parent of the other?

Comment: Why FF or Chrome? I have the problem in IE 8.0

Comment: no parent of the other. Seems, problem is because this aLink is the same where is clicked. But how to solve....

Comment: "why FF or chrome" - because I know that both of these have the "inspect element" option on the right click menu. IE8 might have also, I don't run that. The point was to see what the attributes for these divs and anchors are at each stage

Answer (score 1):

you do not seem to be the only one with the issue : cf http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hidden-visible-broken-in-ie8

The problems seems to append in IE8 when a display:none element has visible elements nearby. This seems to fool the jquery algorithm that detects :visible.

I can advice you to test with a class instead of :visible and :hidden :

```
if ($("#divLiked" + CommentID).hasClass('like')) {
      $("#divLiked" + CommentID).removeClass('like').show();
      $("#aLike" + CommentID).text('Unlike');
} else {
      $("#divLiked" + CommentID).addClass('like').show();
      $("#aLike" + CommentID).text('Like');
}
```

I hope this will help you,

Jerome Wagner